# JanusGraph graphTraversalSource.next() throws java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

`GraphTraversalSource` throws `NoSuchElementException` when I try to find an edge though a string value id, but i can find the edge with this id.

When I use a `String` value edge id to find the edge in JanusGraph, I declared a `GraphTraversalSource` instance `g`, and used the code such as:

```
g.E("edge-id").next()
```

Except time limit, is there any other configuration that could lead to such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes from multi-thread.
When I make some vertex in a transaction, and this transaction has not committed, at that time, if I ask the vertexes on the other transaction, Exception would happened.